# Why is the destination colum not showing the ip address in wireshark?

Tags: dns, ip, wireshark

[image]

When i ping a website in cmd in windows and use wireshark to capture DNS packets, it dosen't show me the ip address in the destination column but instead instead it shows me a different address type. I am assuming that it's a mac address.

Can someone tell me how I can change this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are offtopic here but what you see in Destination is an IPv6 address. 
There is nothing to change, Wireshark is just displaying what is happening on the network and for these lines it was an exchange happening over IPv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are IPv6 addresses - if you want to see only IPv4 addresses you can configure the application to not use v6 or disable it on the network interface altogether.